# C# trayicon using wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, trayicon

I'm very new to programming C#, though I've scripted C# in unity3D for a few years.
I'm currently trying to make a WPF tray icon, all the sources I've found on the net tell me to use

```
System.Windows.Forms
```

However .Forms is not available in System.Windows for me, and I have no idea why not. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to add references to the System.Window.Forms and System.Drawing assemblies and then you use it like this. Suppose you try to minimize the Window to tray icon and show it again when user click that icon:

```
public partial class Window : System.Windows.Window
{

    public Window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon ni = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
        ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("Main.ico");
        ni.Visible = true;
        ni.DoubleClick += 
            delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
            {
                this.Show();
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            };
    }

    protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
            this.Hide();

        base.OnStateChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent the word reference helped me to find out how and where.
And I now have a tray icon, thanks =)

Comment: If you've got it in a window with System.Windows references you will run into some ambiguity issues. I solved it with adding a name to the using:  using WinForms = System.Windows.Forms; Then called it with WinForms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new WinForms.NotifyIcon();

Comment: Works excellently, thumbs up.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a reference to the System.Windows.Forms.dll and then use the NotifyIcon class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx