# Minimizing Application to system tray using WPF ( Not using NotifyIcon )

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, wpf-controls, notifyicon

I am finished making my application and now I want to incorporate " minimizing into the system tray feature " for it . I read up a good article  [minimize app to system tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625421/minimize-app-to-system-tray) . I realized that these make use of the Windows.Form class .

Unfortunately I have used Windows Presentation Foundation [WPF reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268.aspx) to make my applications UI . Now I see that the NotifyIcon is not supported in WPF. I see that there is an open source library on CodePlex that simulates the NotifyIcon properties [WPF Contrib](http://wpfcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NotifyIcon&referringTitle=Home&ProjectName=wpfcontrib) I have not used it as yet .

Now I am in a fix . Here are my questions :-

a) I don't want to incorporate a 3'rd party library just for one single component .

b) Can I do the minimizing feature without NotifyIcon on WPF? If yes then how can someone give me leads please ?

Or maybe I should revert my UI back to using Windows Forms ?

Comment: Edit your post; try to add links like this [link text](http:/.......com).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you'll reconsider your reluctance to using an external component, I recommend WPF [NotifyIcon](http://www.hardcodet.net/projects/wpf-notifyicon). I've used it. It's straightforward and works well.

It does not just rely on the corresponding WinForms component, but is a purely independent control which leverages several features of the WPF framework in order to display rich tooltips, popups, context menus, and balloon messages.

Comment: Thanks @Marksl : Good to know that it is stable and working well for you . I will wait for someother people to throw in their views . Or if they have any other suggestions .

Comment: For my project, I was planning on merging all assemblies together with ILMerge. In the end WPF NotifyIcon was so small, I just copied the code directly in the project - perhaps not best practice, but it was quick. There's really not much code to it. I'm interested to see if there are other approaches too.

Comment: I have also used this in my project and works well. You can strip the code which you don't need and just add the minimal required code into your application. I also tried a lot of things at that time and this was the best possible solution.

Comment: @akjoshi . Thanks for your valueable inputs . I will consider using it in my application .

Comment: It's also available through [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf/)

Comment: Bad news for the future though, it doesn't seem to be totally DPI aware.  On high DPI monitors it looks like it doesn't correctly place the pop-up menu.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this post today.

For reference, I also solved this some time back. It works very well and the only time I have had a bit of an issue is occasionally on some multi-display set ups.

This was before GITs and NuGets were the in-thing, I will place it in a GIT repo if there is interest.

[CodeProject Article Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36788/WPF-XAML-NotifyIcon-and-Taskbar-System-Tray-Popup)

Answer (score -1):

**Solution with System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon**

Here is a thread , which helped me a lot .

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12428063/10305444

```
public partial class Window : System.Windows.Window{


public Window()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon ni = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
    ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("Main.ico");
    ni.Visible = true;
    ni.DoubleClick += 
        delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            this.Show();
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        };
}

protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
        this.Hide();

    base.OnStateChanged(e);
}}
```