# How to make the notify icon of a WPF application appear in the system tray on windows startup?

Tags: wpf, notifyicon

I have a WPF application for searching in a SharePoint site. I have defined notify icon in the same which is executing as per my requirements. I want this notify icon to sit in the system tray on Windows start-up. So, how to go about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Minimizing Application to system tray using WPF ( Not using NotifyIcon )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700606/minimizing-application-to-system-tray-using-wpf-not-using-notifyicon)

Comment: I am done with that part. I want that icon to appear by default on Windows start-up.

Comment: @Sane.Amit add your application .exe to the windows startup list to execute it on startup and thus bring the notify icon up? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089601/run-the-application-at-windows-startup <- check this for ways to run your application on windows startup

Comment: @Viv I think that if the application will be used on some other system than this thing will have to be done in other systems too. Can't something be defined in WPF application itself for this purpose?

Comment: @Sane.Amit check the link in my previous comment. It shows ways to "toggle" the feature of having an app startup with the os from your app. You'd normally have the same option via your app installers as well and then let the user toggle it on/off from your app.