# WPF : Application Toolbar

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to make a login screen for my WPF application, but I want this login screen to be constantly available at a corner of the screen like an `application toolbar` the application should be hidden and only display when the mouse hovers over a part of the toolbar.

I have searched for solutions, but the only ones I have seen were implemented in c++ for windows applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard caveats about "always available" apply here of course.

That said, you could easily create a window with `WindowStyle="None"` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and position it wherever you want. This eliminates *all* window chrome, making it appear that the content is just sitting on the screen. By handling the `MouseOver` event you could expand to show your additional controls.

Other tricks can be used to have the application live in the tray, etc. For example:

[Minimizing Application to system tray using WPF ( Not using NotifyIcon )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700606/minimizing-application-to-system-tray-using-wpf-not-using-notifyicon)