# How to minimize Windows Store app to system tray

Tags: wpf, windows-runtime, system-tray

I have created a windows 8.1 project by selecting the template in the screenshot below:

[image]

I want to minimize it to system tray and keep it running while it's in the tray. How do I do that for a store app? I found [WPF Application that only has a tray icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472633/wpf-application-that-only-has-a-tray-icon) and some similar links but I cannot reference System.Windows.Forms namespace in a Runtime app it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't minimize Winows Store Apps into the system tray, only Windows Forms and WPF apps can do that.

You can help that happen by voting here [UWP System tray support](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/12817866-uwp-system-tray-support)

Comment: Is it not a Windows Runtime app that I have created (not a UWP app)?

Comment: @AshishAgrawal Yeah, my answer goes well for both Win8 or UWP apps, it's the same

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks.

Comment: I need to do it anyhow. Can you tell me if there's any workaround other than moving the entire code base to a wpf project?

Comment: @AshishAgrawal I don't know any workaround, not sure if it exists

Comment: Based on my research, it seems that it's not possible for wpf applications as well without using a third party library like: http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon

Comment: @AshishAgrawal oh yes you can , you need just to reference the System.Window.Forms and System.Drawing assemblies here is how http://stackoverflow.com/a/12428063/2002048

Comment: I see it. Thanks again :)