# Where does the Windows "Edit Colors" control come from and can I use it in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to add a color palette to a WPF program I am working on. My first choice would be the "Edit Colors" dialog box from MS Paint, as shown in the image attached to this question. I have seen this dialog box in many different programs, leading me to believe it is some sort of standard control available to Windows apps. If that is the case, is there a way for me to access it using C# and the .NET Framework? Am I mistaken about where this control comes from? I am aware of several packages I can use to get color pickers such as WPF Toolkit Extended, but I was hoping I could use this one without adding any new packages to my project.

[image: Edit Colors window]

Comment: You can use the same control from WinForms https://stackoverflow.com/a/63277504/1043380

Comment: Thanks. Is there any common practices regarding mixing Windows.Forms controls into WPF applications? Is that discouraged, or is it not really an issue if I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116708